# How to change/update custom theme preview image (thumbnail)

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I creating a custom theme on odoo (v14) and I would like to add/change/update the thumbnail image  for this theme on **Pic a Theme** page. Where should I edit and add an image?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a thumbnail image for the theme you are creating, you just need to indicate the directory of that image on **`__manifest__.py`** file.

```
'images': [
      'static/description/screenshot.jpg',
  ],
```